# How to read Excel datetime when column is formatted for timestamp

Tags: r

I am attempting to read several Excel files into a single dataframe but I am running into the following issue.

My final dataframe is outputting the Excel cell formatted value 23:33:00

The Excel formula bar for this cell has a value of 2/1/2015  11:33:00 PM, which will be formatted to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS in my final dataframe.

Is there a way to read the full datetime for a column when it is formatted as a timestamp?  Thanks in advance for any help!

```
#gdata is a package that contains tools for data manipulation, example: read.xls
library('gdata')

#Creates xls file global variables
filePath = "..."
filenames = list.files(path = filePath, pattern = '[.]xls', recursive = F)

#Initializes final data frame structure
finaldf = data.frame(integer(0))

#List of columns needed output files
listOfColumns = c("Time", "CT Depth", "CT Pressure", "CT Pipe Weight", "CT Running Speed", "Fluid Rate", "Wellhead Pressure","CT PIPE WEIGHT-PIPE HEAVY (lbf)","CT PIPE WEIGHT-PIPE LIGHT (lbf)","FLUID RATE (bpm)")
for (idx in 1:length(filenames)) {
  print(idx)
  filenamePath = paste(filePath, filenames[idx], sep = "")
  df = read.xls(xls = filenamePath , sheet = 1, header = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
  df2 = data.frame(Time = df$Time)
  for (jdx in 1:length(listOfColumns)) {
    if (is.null(df[[listOfColumns[jdx]]])) {
      df2[[listOfColumns[jdx]]] = NA
    } else { df2[[listOfColumns[jdx]]] = df[[listOfColumns[jdx]]]}
  }
  if (nrow(finaldf) == 0) {
    finaldf = df2
  } else {
    finaldf = rbind(finaldf, df2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Look into `?as.POSIXct` it can handle full time dates, the package `lubridate` may be helpful too, but check out POSIXct first as it is in base R.

Comment: As you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254215/date-time-am-pm-in-r  The AM PM time can be handled easily. Further explain here https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html

Comment: as.POSIXct worked perfectly, thank you very much